# ag: search exact string, not a pattern

Tags: regex, ag

## My Problem

I'm searching for `Application(service)` in my files using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher). Since ag treats strings as regular expression patterns, I have to escape the parens and use:

```
ag 'Application\(service\)'
```

This is cumbersome and easy to miss, especially when there are multiple regex symbols in my search.

## What have I tried

- Search the manual
- Escape the regex chars (works, but error-prone)

## My Question

**How can I instruct ag to treat the search term as a literal string, instead of a regex pattern?**

Comment: Have you tried `--literal`/`-Q`?

Comment: Try using quoted literal and place your string between `\Q` and `\E` like this `\QApplication(service)\E` and as I know `ag` tool uses PCRE based engine so it should work most likely, though not sure as never used that tool.

Comment: @georg Great, don't know how I missed it. Answer it and I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: This is less of a programming question and more of a "how do I use ag?" question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The option you're looking for is

> -Q --literal: Do not parse PATTERN as a regular expression. Try to match it literally.

@ https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md: